# Precision of floating-point numbers

Tags: python, floating-point

What precision are the floating-point numbers in Python? Is it always double-precision or is it implementation or platform specific? Does it differ in, say, CPython and PyPy?

Comment: Good question. (Please don't downvote!). To add colour, in C and C++ it's implementation specific. In Java it must be IEEE754. As for python, I have no idea. A quick Google doesn't shed any light on this (for me) either.

Comment: Check this for CPython2: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: There's a clue here http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/python/.  The top line "Almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE 754 double precision.". So it looks like it's the same as C and C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba is right: in *theory* Python just uses whatever the C double is. In *practice* you can always assume IEEE 754 binary64 format. There are enough places in the Python source and the Python test suite where that assumption is made implicitly that we (the Python core devs) would hear about it if anyone were trying to compile / test / run Python on non-IEEE 754 hardware. (E.g., see: http://bugs.python.org/issue27444)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ok, so if I understood correctly, I can safely assume 64-bits for CPython. But what about other implementations like PyPy, Pyston, IronPython, Jython? Are those free to use other representations or do those have to follow CPython tests? And what about 32-bit hardware, still 64-bits doubles (via software emulation, I presume)?

Comment: @EcirHana: IronPython will use .NET Doubles, Jython will use Java's Double. In both cases I believe those types are specified to be IEEE 754 binary64 format by the appropriate language spec. I don't know about PyPy, but would be surprised if it's doing anything other than using the C double. No idea about Pyston. Most 32-bit hardware supports 64-bit doubles out of the box (certainly Intel x86 does); no need for software emulation, so yes, everything will still be binary64 there too.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks, if you post your answers below, I'll accept them.

Comment: @EcirHana: No time right now (I'd need to look up all the proper links to create a decent answer); maybe later. I'd be happy if someone else beats me to it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson your answers are more than "decent" for my needs as they stand but as you wish... Thanks once more!

Comment: .NET Doubles and Java Doubles *must* both be IEEE754.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ***Python*** documentation:

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using **double in C**;
>   information about the ***precision*** and internal representation of
>   floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is
>   running is available in ***sys.float_info***.

[**sys.float_info**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) is a struct sequence holding information about the float type. It contains low level information about the precision and internal representation.

```
import sys

print(sys.float_info.mant_dig)
```

`mant_dig` attribute points to *float precision: the number of base-radix digits in the significand of a float*

> Almost all platforms map Python floats to [IEEE 754](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/) double
>   precision.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm aware of `sys.float_info`, the problem is that "usually". I could reverse the question, when is it not C double?

Comment: @EcirHana: For CPython, it's *always* C double. That's hard-coded in the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/floatobject.h#L17).

Comment: Yup, this is good enough for me. (Although it would be nice to have a link to any official python documentation). Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.float_info
```

sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)

Found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric
Sec 4.4

Does this help you?